# Can "alight" be used to mean "light"?

Tags: meaning, semantics, prefixes

Usually, the verb *(to) alight* can be used to express:

- Landing somewhere
- Disembarking a vehicle

But since you can also *set something alight*, I've been wondering if someone would light my cigar if I told him, "please alight."

In other words, does the `a-` prefix bear a constructive or destructive meaning?

Comment: Yes, you could. It would be a unique usage. There's nothing inherently wrong in that. It would probably be marked wrong on a test.

Comment: I can imagine Geoff Pullum's advice on 'how to respond to someone requesting "Please alight" '.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OED attests to several verb meanings of *alight* that have fallen out of common usage (marked *rare*):

> 1. *trans.* To shed light on; to illuminate, enlighten (*lit.* and *fig.*).
>
>    > 1999  D. Tobin *Passage to Center* 301:  Such repose alights the face of The Tollund Man and Gunnar.
> 2. *trans.* To set light to; to light, ignite. Also *fig.*
>
>    > 2009 S. Akhter *Faith & Philos. Islam* vi. 89:  The Holy Quran is an extraordinary pearl... Every fruit of good luck is found in it and every torch is alighted from it.

I would not use them in modern communication except for deliberate literary effect.

The etymology of this verb use of *alight* is treated as uncertain, but it may be a reduction of the obsolete *onlight*, which also means to shed light upon or to cause to shine. The OED further suggests that the adjective/adverb use of *alight* derived from the verb and was later reinterpreted by analogy to *afire* and *aflame*.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think, you can ask someone to "alight your cigar".. you can probably say "do you have a matchbox/ lighter so that my cigar is alight". In other words, alight refers to 'fire' only as an adjective and not as a verb.

Comment: Nice answer, if you provide a source.

Comment: my go-to online dictionary, merriam-webster, makes this exact distinction in its definitions for [alight](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alight).  (However, your example sentence, "so that my cigar is alight", sounds horribly contrived....)

Comment: Your example isn't right; that's like saying "Do you have a matchbox/lighter **so that my cigar is on fire**?". You'd have to say something like "Do you have a matchbox/lighter **to set my cigar alight**?" (although as mentioned above, that would still be very contrived".